# Citrix session timeout

Tags: citrix

Hi I am using Citrix for accessing my application. I use web browser to login to Citrix session, the client I am using is 9.2.

Once I have logged into Citrix machine and stay idle for 15 minutes it automatically logs off. I do not want Citrix to automaticall log me off.

I do not have admin access to Citrix servers as I am just a user. I was told by someone that if I increase BrowserTimeout in APPSRV.ini file(located at APPLICATION data in my local machine) my problem would get solved, however it does not seem this is helping.

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The idle timeout needs to be configured by a Citrix XenApp administrator.

Comment: Yes - this is my design.